# JavaScript // Inner Html Loses Form View

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, printing

I've been trying to print a form (asp:panel) with javascript. But i have 2 problem.

1)After print button, my form loses style. (It's coming with aspPanel.InnerHtml)

2)I want to control the page sizes depend on print page. (Like if line doesn't fit the page, pass it other page)

I'm posting with my screen shots. Ideas?

[image]

[image]

```
function PrintForm()
    {            
        var formpanel = document.getElementById("<%= QuestForm.ClientID%>");
        var mainWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800');
        mainWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Adapazarı</title>');
        mainWindow.document.write('<head/><body>');
        mainWindow.document.write(formpanel.innerHTML);
        mainWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mainWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            mainWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include `media="all"` on your `<link>` tag, your stylesheet won't get applied when you print the page. Adding `media="all"` should solve your problem.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
```

Comment: It doestn't work. (Also i use style in tags) There are still spaces between my elements on print window.

Comment: If you're using `<style>`, add the `media="all"` right on the style tag, like so: `<style media="all">`. Try adding the styles under a media query `@media print {.....}`, and perhaps use `!important` to override any potential conflicts.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works. I'm using style in every element (because i did think it might be about print window doesnt apply my css link) Like;
<div style="width:80%;"> something</div>
So are u advicing that add media="all" in every div?

Comment: Ah ok. In general, you almost always want to avoid using inline styling as it can cause a lot of maintainability issues down the road and just using classes/IDS are not only more efficient, but also a lot easier to change.

 I'd suggest you gather up all of your styles, and toss it in a stylesheet file, and link the file with a `media="all"` property as shown above.

Let me know how that works.